# Case not work in doctrine query builder where clause

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I am facing issue with mysql CASE in where clause of doctrine,

```
 $rides_q1 = $em->getRepository('IRRideBundle:Ride');
    $query = $rides_q1->createQueryBuilder('a')
                     ->where('(CASE WHEN a.ephemeral = 1 THEN a.date_beginning < NOW() AND a.date_ending > NOW()ELSE a.ephemeral = 0 END) AND a.active = 1 AND a.status = 5')                  
     ->getQuery();
$ridesQuery = $query->execute();



**[Syntax Error] line 0, col 93: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ELSE, got '<'**

[2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 93: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ELSE, got '<'   +
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT a FROM IR\RideBundle\Entity\Ride a WHERE (CASE WHEN ephemeral = 1 THEN date_beginning < NOW() AND date_ending > NOW()ELSE ephemeral = 0 END)
```

I want to prepare this sql query, its working fine with phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM ride WHERE (CASE WHEN ephemeral = 1 THEN date_beginning < NOW() AND date_ending > NOW()ELSE ephemeral = 0 END) AND active = 1 AND `status_id` = 5 ORDER BY `date_ending` DESC
```

Comment: Normally you don't use CASE in WHERE. Use boolean logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` expression in `WHERE` is wrong. You could convert it to normal compound condition like

```
(CASE WHEN a.ephemeral = 1 THEN a.date_beginning < NOW() AND a.date_ending > NOW()ELSE a.ephemeral = 0 END)
```

To

```
SELECT * FROM ride
WHERE ((a.ephemeral = 1 
       and a.date_beginning < NOW() 
       AND a.date_ending > NOW()) 
  OR a.ephemeral = 0)
  AND a.active = 1 
  AND a.status = 5
ORDER BY `date_ending` DESC
```

Comment: Yes, i can omit CASE and use simple AND OR query, thanks

Comment: @JaysukhMaghodiya, consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Method `createQueryBuilder()` used when you need build Query with Doctrine.
For example:

```
 public function findPostsQuery()
  {
      $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
      $qb
          ->where('p.postStatus = :postStatus')
          ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
          ->setParameter('postStatus', true);
      return $qb->getQuery();
  }
```

If you wont create Custom query - use `createQuery()` method.
For example:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $query = $em->createQuery(
     'SELECT p
     FROM AppBundle:Product p
     WHERE p.price > :price
     ORDER BY p.price ASC'
 )->setParameter('price', 19.99);

 $products = $query->getResult();
```

Official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql) help you