# Doctrine DQL WHERE with CASE?

Tags: php, sql, orm, doctrine, dql

### Not a duplicate.

I ask how to make CASE work, or why it doesn't work(especially given that the same CASE expression works in pure SQL). I am NOT looking for alternate solutions.

---

I'm working with the Doctrine ORM(and its SQL-derivative query language - DQL) and trying to create a DQL query with a CASE expression in the WHERE clause, but Doctrine throws an error at me.

DQL:
`SELECT p FROM Entity\Product p WHERE (CASE WHEN p.price < 20 THEN p.quantity >= 30 ELSE p.quantity > 5 END)`

I receive the following error:
`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 87: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ELSE, got '>'`
(around the `>= 30` above)

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know DQL supports CASE expressions. I've found SO answers that use them. At the very least the stack trace has a parser call acknowledging that.

The same SQL statement:
`SELECT p.* FROM product p WHERE (CASE WHEN p.price < 20 THEN p.quantity >= 30 ELSE p.quantity > 5 END)`
works as it should.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Doctrine or DQL, so this may not be a relevant suggestion. What happens if you remove the `>` from `p.quantity >= 30`? So it would become `p.quantity = 30`.

Comment: Error is the same, just says `, got '='` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how well DQL will cope with parsing a case statement in a where clause, it's certainly not a construction I've seen very often (if at all). Is there any reason to not just write this using `where (...) or (...)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case not work in doctrine query builder where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890433/case-not-work-in-doctrine-query-builder-where-clause)

Comment: @iainn More concise logic? Too tired now to think of an example that CASE solves significantly better than a heaping mass of conditionals, but there probably are such _cases_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of a colleague, and based on the [formal grammar](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf) of DQL, what I am doing wrong is *trying to use an unsupported feature*.

At present(as of Doctrine v2.6) DQL simply does not support the CASE expression evaluating to a *conditional expression*. It may ONLY evaluate to a [`ScalarExpression`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#case-expressions) as defined in the syntax which cannot be an instance of `ConditionalExpression`.

```
ScalarExpression      ::= SimpleArithmeticExpression | StringPrimary | DateTimePrimary | StateFieldPathExpression | BooleanPrimary | CaseExpression | InstanceOfExpression
CaseExpression        ::= GeneralCaseExpression | SimpleCaseExpression | CoalesceExpression | NullifExpression
GeneralCaseExpression ::= "CASE" WhenClause {WhenClause}* "ELSE" ScalarExpression "END"
WhenClause            ::= "WHEN" ConditionalExpression "THEN" ScalarExpression
SimpleCaseExpression  ::= "CASE" CaseOperand SimpleWhenClause {SimpleWhenClause}* "ELSE" ScalarExpression "END"
CaseOperand           ::= StateFieldPathExpression | TypeDiscriminator
SimpleWhenClause      ::= "WHEN" ScalarExpression "THEN" ScalarExpression
CoalesceExpression    ::= "COALESCE" "(" ScalarExpression {"," ScalarExpression}* ")"
NullifExpression      ::= "NULLIF" "(" ScalarExpression "," ScalarExpression ")"
```

Comment: I replaced case expressions with where expressions and it worked. Took some hours to figure it out